# Multiple sticky header rows inside a tab in Angular/Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I followed the example on the Angular Material website to create a table with multiple sticky header rows. This works perfectly. But, when I take the table and move it inside a tab, only one of the rows sticks as I scroll down. Can this be fixed?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-3zzcw7

Notice how when you scroll down in the first table, the first two rows stick. But when you scroll down in the second table, only the second row sticks.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly apply `position: sticky` and setting `top` equals to height of the above row for the second-row header i.e. `top: 56px`, and this will make the second-row header also sticky. This is the CSS you need to add.

```
.mat-header-row:nth-child(2) {
    position: sticky;
    top: 56px;
}
```

And here is the forked example with this change applied.
https://angular-bklajw-rqkyjm.stackblitz.io

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sticky positions are applied at run time. You can try to fix it using css.

- First add a class to your 2nd row.

```
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true" class="second-row"></tr>
```

- Add following css to set the top position. 55px is the height of
  first row.

```
.second-row .mat-header-cell.mat-table-sticky {
  top: 55px !important;
}
```

Working example:- https://angular-bklajw-rwgxn9.stackblitz.io

Not the cleanest of solution but will get the work done.